# Authorization is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I'm developing a simple register and login form for authorizing users.

Registration works fine, but login doesn't. Here is full code:

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
    }
    Route::get('/signup/', 'RegistController@getRegister');
    Route::post('/signup/create', 'RegistController@postRegister');
    Route::get('/login/', 'RegistController@getLogin');
    Route::post('/login/enter', 'RegistController@postLogin');
    Route::any('/', 'ItemsController@index');
    Route::get('/items', 'ItemsController@index');
    Route::get('/items/{itemid}', 'ItemsController@item');
});
```

RegistController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use View;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use App\User;
use App\Code;
use Auth;

class RegistController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Каталог - авторизация ',
            'pagetitle' => 'Каталог',
            'subtitle' => 'Авторизация'
        ];

        //dd($data);
        return View::make('incs.login', $data);
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request["email"]);
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request["email"], 'password' => $request["password"]), true)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')->withInput()->withErrors(array('login_error' => 'Неверный логин или пароль'));
        }
        return "login success";
    }
    protected function login_validator(array $data)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'email.required' => 'Е-mail не задан',
            'email.email' => 'Е-mail не в формате',
            'password.required' => 'Пароль не задан',
        ];
        return Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('cont')
    <h2>{{$subtitle}}</h2>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach


    <form action="/login/enter" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name='email' value='{{Request::old('email')}}'/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Войти</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

When I open any page after login and in my routes.php put:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $user = Auth::user();
}
```

`$Auth::check` returns false and `$user` is empty.

[In Firebug I can see laravel_session and remember_web cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6nug.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

change your this line

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request["email"], 'password' => $request["password"]), true)) {
```

to this

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->get("email"), 'password' => $request->get("password")), true)) {
```

see the result and update me, also make `dd($request->all());`  on top of the above mentioned line, tell me what results you get

Comment: dd($request->all()) array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "zZlfkQMgWH9setw7aGmpJyA12VJ6bv5jXHEWynzw"
  "email" => "dede1111111@mail.ru"
  "password" => "1230"
]

Comment: if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->get("email"), 'password' => $request-->get("password")), true))  but dd(Auth::check()); in routes return false

Comment: `Auth::check()` return false because, you are not logged in yet, once you loggedin properly, then you can use this method `Auth::check()`

Comment: How login properly? I login in form and Attempt method

Comment: I use Auth:check() in home or other page of site after login in form

Comment: if you are login properly then why you are using `Auth::check()` instead use `Auth` middleware with routes, which will check automatically for the login look this route. 
`Route::get('/items', ['middleware'=>'Auth' 'uses'=>'ItemsController@index']);`

Comment: use this Route::any('/', ['middleware'=>'Auth', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
 Route::get('/items', ['middleware'=>'Auth', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@index']);
 Route::get('/items/{itemid}', ['middleware'=>'Auth', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@item']); and see erorr  ErrorException in Pipeline.php line 124: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth' does not have a method 'handle'

Comment: it works!!!  Route::any('/', ['middleware'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
 Route::get('/items', ['middleware'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@index']);
 Route::get('/items/{itemid}', ['middleware'=>'auth', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@item']);  auth must be lowercase

Comment: Yes, auth must be lower case while using as middleware in routes